# Test method still calls the actual method despite mock

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, nunit, moq

So I have some initial setup that looks like this:

```
    ILoginManager _loginManager;
    Mock<IValidations> _validations;
    Mock<IAccountRepository> _accountRepository;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _loginManager = new LoginManager();
        _validations = new Mock<IValidations>();
        _accountRepository = new Mock<IAccountRepository>();
    }
```

Then I have the test method that looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Login_ValidUser()
    {
        _validations.Setup(val => val.IsValidAccount(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(true);
        _accountRepository.Setup(repo => repo.Login(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(()=>new User());
        var result = _loginManager.Login(new User());
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

And the actual method that looks like this:

```
    public User Login(User user)
    {
        if (user != null && _validations.IsValidAccount(user))
        {
            return _accountDal.Login(user);
        }
        log.Error("User null or not valid");
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that the test method still calls the original methods so it ignores the mock setup.

Comment: You set up `_validations` and `_accountRepository`, but I don't see you using that in `_loginManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those dependencies would have had to have been injected directly into the manager in order for them to be available for mocking when testing

For example

```
public class LoginManager : ILoginManager {
    private readonly IValidations _validations;
    private readonly IAccountRepository _accountDal;

    public LoginManager(IValidations validations, IAccountRepository accountDal) {
        _validations = validations;
        _accountDal = accountDal;
    }

    public User Login(User user) {
        if (user != null && _validations.IsValidAccount(user)) {
            return _accountDal.Login(user);
        }
        log.Error("User null or not valid");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your current example is not using the mocks in the class under test because they were not injected.

Refactor the `LoginManager` class and the test accordingly

```
ILoginManager _loginManager;
Mock<IValidations> _validations;
Mock<IAccountRepository> _accountRepository;

[SetUp]
public void Setup() {        
    _validations = new Mock<IValidations>();
    _accountRepository = new Mock<IAccountRepository>();
    _loginManager = new LoginManager(_validations.Object, _accountRepository.Object);
}   

[Test]
public void Login_ValidUser() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = new User();
    _validations.Setup(val => val.IsValidAccount(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(true);
    _accountRepository.Setup(repo => repo.Login(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(()=> user);

    //Act
    var actual = _loginManager.Login(expected);

    //Assert
    Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);        
}
```